# I'm not able to remove the whitespace in my html document

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have uploaded the screenshot of my webpage and also the HTML, CSS and JavaScript. There are some white spaces in the `<h1>` tag and also in the `<section>` tag which I'm not able to resolve.

[image: screenshot of my website]

```js
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.mySlides {display:none;}


.logo{
 float:left;
 margin-right: 100px;
}

.navigation{
background-color:skyblue;
height:55px; 
}

.navbar li  {
 list-style-type: none;
 display:inline;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-right: 4em;
}

.navbar a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}

header{
    float:left;

}

.sidebar h1{
    
 font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
 text-align: center;
}


.footer{
 clear:both;
 background-color: grey;
    height: 207px;
 width:100%;
 }

.links{
 margin-bottom:3px;
 
}
.bottomlinks{
 list-style-type: none;
 font-family: verdana;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-right:100px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 55px;
 float:left;
}

.bottomlinks li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;

}

.address{
 margin-top:15px;
 margin-right: 400px;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-family: verdana;
 font-weight: bold;
 float:left;
}

.social-icons{
 margin-top:70px;
 float:right;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.social-icons li{

 display: inline;
 margin-right: 20px;
}

.social-icons a {
color: white;
opacity:0.8;
}


.social-icons i{
 font-size: 1.5em;
}

.fa-facebook {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    
}
.fa-facebook:hover {
    background-color: #3d5b99;
}
.fa-twitter {
    padding:10px 12px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    
}
.fa-twitter:hover {
    background-color: #00aced;
}
.fa-instagram {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    
}
.fa-instagram:hover {
    background-color:#bc2a8d;
}
.fa-youtube {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    
}
.fa-youtube:hover {
    background-color: #e64a41;
}
.fa-linkedin {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    
}
.fa-linkedin:hover {
    background-color: #0073a4;
}
.fa-google-plus {
    padding:10px 9px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    
}
.fa-google-plus:hover {
    background-color:  #d34836;
}

.copyright{

 clear: both;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cafe New Bengaluru | Home</title>
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="logo">
<a href=""><img src="logo.png" width="70px" height="50px"></a>
</div>

<nav class="navigation">
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>


<header>
<img src="home.jpg" width="840px" height="400x" alt="Hotel Entry Image">
</header>


<section class="sidebar">
<h1>Menu of the day</h1>
<img class="mySlides" src="pekingrice.jpg" width="500px" height="326px">
<img class="mySlides" src="chickenmomo.jpeg" width="500px" height="326px">
<img class="mySlides" src="lollipop.jpg" width="500px" height="326px">
</section>

<footer class="footer">
<ul class="bottomlinks">
<li><p class="links">Links</p></li>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="address">
<li><p class="links">Address</p></li>
<li>#123, Arcade Heights</li>
<li> Delta Block</li>
<li> Indiranagar, StageII</li>
<li>Karnatake: 560008</li>
</ul>

<ul class="social-icons">
<li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<p class="copyright">©2017.All Rights Reserved </p>

</footer>


<script src="myfile.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check the margins and paddings computed in your browsers inspector tool

Comment: Please update this to include a [mcve] with additional emphasis on ***minimal***.

Comment: set the margin .. of sidebar ..  in your css

Answer (score 0):

> Try Do This.

**Problem Is Here**

```
<section class="sidebar">
<h1>Menu of the day</h1>
<img class="mySlides" src="pekingrice.jpg" width="500px" height="326px">
<img class="mySlides" src="chickenmomo.jpeg" width="500px" height="326px">
<img class="mySlides" src="lollipop.jpg" width="500px" height="326px">
</section>
```

**You Have To Set The margin and padding for you section tag or his for class in Css**

*Example:*

```
.sidebar{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

> Note:

**You have To Adjust the image `chickenmomo.jpg` width and height  for perfect set in section**

Answer (score 0):

margin spacing is the problem.Embed this to your HTML code after body tag

```
<style type="text/css">
    .sidebar h1{
        margin: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

this code fix `<h1></h1>` but that slider is not fixed you need to change that slider css to fix that bug